# error in fmincon Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

`

```
function [LLF, LL, H  ] = garchlike(data)


p=1;
q=1;


 if isempty(q)
    m=p;
 else
     m  =  max(p,q);   
 end

%this are the parameters
psi=[0.01;0.01];
 gamma=[0;0.02;0.02;0];
 lambda=[0;0.03;0.03;0];
  A=[1;-0.04;-0.03;1];

 stdestimate = std(data,1);                      
data   =  [stdestimate ; data];
T =  size(data,1);

B=(reshape(A,2,2))^-1;
%I am squaring each element of the inverse of A
B2=((reshape(A,2,2))^-1).^2;
%getting the Bl matrix(squared interactions)

Bl=[B2(1,:);B(1,:).*B(2,:);B2(2,:)];

garchc=Bl*psi;
garcha=Bl*(reshape(gamma,2,2))*reshape(A.^2,2,2);
garchb= Bl*(reshape(lambda,2,2))*reshape(A.^2,2,2);

H(1,1).day=[0.001; 0; 0; 0.002; ];
%convert to matrix

  H(1,1).day=ivech(H(1,1).day);

for t = (m + 1):T


  H(1,t).day= ivech(garchc + garcha*(diag(H(1,t-1).day))+ garchb*(data((t-1),:).^2)');

end
% Getting the loglikelihood
LLF=zeros(1,T);
%the loklikelihood
for t = (m + 2):T

  LLF(t)= log(det(H(1,t).day))+ data(t,:)/(H(1,t).day)*data(t,:)';

end
t=(m+2):T;
LLF=-LLF(t);
LL=sum(LLF);
`
```

I have this function from up and trying to minimize using fmincon:

```
`  [parameters,LLF,EXITFLAG, OUTPUT,HESSIAN] =  fmincon('garchlike',    [psi;gamma;lambda;A],sumA ,sumB ,[] , [] , LB , UB,[],options, data, p , q);`
```

I don't know why is not working and gives me an error :
"Error using garchlike
Error using garchlike
Too many input arguments.
Error in fmincon (line 631)
initVals.f = feval(funfcn{3},X,varargin{:});
Caused by:
    Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FMINCON cannot continue."

Comment: please format it better. This is illegible.

Comment: what does `garchlike` return at the initial condition?

Comment: garchlike will return the loglikelihood(1x800)LLf,then the sum of loglikelihood LL(one value) and the Ht(time varying matrices 3x3)..

Answer (score 0):

"Error using garchlike Too many input arguments." is your problem.

`fmincon` is calling `garchlike([psi;gamma;lambda;A],data, p , q)`, but your `garchlike` only takes 1 argument.

Pro tip: learn how to use the debugger. Start by setting `dbstop if error`.

EDIT: okay, here are some more details. Please read carefully.

Your `garchlike` takes 1 argument as input, while your fmincon is calling it with 4 arguments.
Either (1) you need to remove those 3 extra arguments (namely, data, p, q) from fmincon, or (2) make garchlike take 3 more arguments!!

Comment: I was using debugger and did what you told me,but still doesn't tell me more.It shows me the line 631 in fmincon.Sorry but I just start using matlab and for the univariate case was going well the function:(

Comment: I appreciate very much if you could tell me what to  do,to improve and fix the error ?

Comment: I tryed to take also all the arguments and not only one but gives me the same error..

Comment: with the debugger you can see exactly what is fed in the `feval` statement.

Comment: I used the debugger and check the line 631 which is: initVals.f = feval(funfcn{3},X,varargin{:}); The initVals.f(is 14x1,the initial values I have),funfcn(is 1x5 cell,'fun' 'fmincon'  garchlike [] []),X(14x1),varargin(empty).Also tells me that the fmincon must have at least 4 inputs,don't I have 4?

Comment: why did it return 14x1? funfct{3} should reply a scalar.

Comment: If you didn't understand my update, I will not reply to your comments any longer.

Comment: In other words, remove `data,p,q` from your `fmincon`.

Comment: I already removed the data,o,q from the fmincon..I was doing this before you told me..And got the same error..However just for your knowlodge I found the error: is just in terms of they way I apply fmincon at my garchlike and the inital values were the problem.